# Java ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, concurrency

I have a RESTful application that communicates with an external server. I process a very large amount of data, so I aggregate this data and send it to that server periodically using the @Scheduled annotation (every 2 seconds). The problem is that sometimes, for unknown reasons, random data doesn't get sent. I don't know what could be the cause.

```
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000")
    void sendToApi() {
        var apiRequest = prepareRequests();
        webClient.sendRequests(apiRequest);
    }
```

```
    private final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ApiRequest> apiRequests = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    private ApiRequest prepareApiRequest() {
        List<ApiRequest> requestsToSend = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRequests ; i++) {
            if (this.apiRequests.peek() == null) {
                break;
            }
            requestsToSend.add(this.apiRequests.poll());
        }
        return new ApiRequest(requestsToSend);
    }
```

Comment: You only show us emptying the queue, so kind of hard to reason about it. And what happens if you produce more than `maxRequests` per 2s on average?

Comment: also best way to debug is just add more logs , in multithreaded env logs are the best way to find exact issue. just add logs after each and every important steps that you are performing with threadId and timestamp, you will find issue easily

Comment: Also I would put a mutex/synchronized block around the loop. Otherwise you might get `Check Then Act` race condition between the `peek` and `poll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fixedRateString** used when each execution of the task is independent.

Note that scheduled tasks don’t run in parallel by default. So even if you used fixedRate, the next task won’t be invoked until the previous one is done.

As per your comment, your data is large, So it might be taking more than 2seconds to complete.

You can try below option:

```
@EnableAsync
public class Task {
    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "2000")
    void sendToApi() {
      var apiRequest = prepareRequests();
      webClient.sendRequests(apiRequest);
    }
}
```